# React Hooks PrivateRoute based on API call don't work when refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have this PrivateRoute:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...other }) => {
  const loggedRef = useRef(false);
  const authData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authData'));

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = () => {
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}auth`,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: {
          email: authData ? authData.email : '',
          client_secret: authData ? authData.client_secret : '',
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          // setLogged(true);
          loggedRef.current = true;
          console.log(loggedRef.current, 'ref');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error, 'error?');
          loggedRef.current = false;
        });
    };
    checkAuth();
  }, [authData]);

  return (
    <Route
      {...other}
      render={(props) =>
        loggedRef.current === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

My Routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';
import Login from './layout/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './auth/PrivateRoute';
import Homepage from './layout/Homepage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`authData` is a localStorage item that is being created when the user logs in with success. Then, `Login` component tries to push to the homepage with `history.push('/')`. And `'/'` is being called by PrivateRoute component that should make a request to the server to check if the stored `authData` is valid.

It works just fine the first time that I try and I'm successfully redirect to `/` but if I refresh the page, I go back to `/login`. What can I do to make it persistent?

Previously, I was using `useState` but it don't work properly with async functions so thats why I'm using `useRef`.

@edit

If needed, this is my `Login` component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  StyledContainer,
  StyledButton,
  StyledForm,
  StyledContentWrapper,
  StyledButtonWrapper,
  StyledErrorMessage,
} from './styled';
import EmailIcon from '../../assets/img/email-icon.svg';
import LockIcon from '../../assets/img/lock-icon.svg';
import { TextInput } from '../../components/TextInput';
import { Logo } from '../../components/Logo';
import { Loading } from '../../components/Loading';
import { Title } from '../../components/Title';

const Login = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, client_secret } = event.target.elements;
    setLoading(true);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}auth`,
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      data: { email: email.value, client_secret: client_secret.value },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        const authData = {
          id_token: response.data.id_token,
          email: email.value,
          client_secret: client_secret.value,
        };
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem('authData', JSON.stringify(authData));
        // window.location.href = '/'; // with this, it works.
        history.push('/'); //if I use history.push, the redirect will not work.
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
      });
  };
  // if (localStorage.getItem('authData')) {
  //   return <Redirect to="/" />;
  // }
  const inputFields = [
    {
      autoComplete: 'email',
      autoFocus: true,
      name: 'email',
      required: true,
      fullWidth: true,
      margin: 'normal',
      id: 'email',
      placeholder: 'E-mail',
      type: 'email',
      icon: <img src={EmailIcon} className="input-icon" alt="E-mail icon" />,
      error: error,
    },
    {
      autoComplete: 'current-password',
      name: 'client_secret',
      required: true,
      fullWidth: true,
      margin: 'normal',
      placeholder: 'Token de acesso',
      id: 'client_secret',
      icon: <img src={LockIcon} className="input-icon" alt="Lock icon" />,
      error: error,
      isPassword: true,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <StyledContainer component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      {loading && <Loading />}
      <StyledContentWrapper>
        <Logo />
        <Title size="1.5rem" margin="4.188rem 0 0 0">
          BEM-VINDO
        </Title>
        <Title size="1.125rem" weight="normal" margin="1.281rem 0 0 0">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, contetur
          <br /> adipiscing elit. Nunc accumsan.
        </Title>
        <StyledForm onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          {inputFields.map((field, index) => (
            <TextInput key={`${field.name}_${index}`} {...field} />
          ))}
          {error && (
            <StyledErrorMessage>
              Credenciais informadas são inválidas, tente novamente
            </StyledErrorMessage>
          )}
          <StyledButtonWrapper>
            <StyledButton
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              error={error.toString()}
            >
              Entrar
            </StyledButton>
          </StyledButtonWrapper>
        </StyledForm>
      </StyledContentWrapper>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `Redirect` component, have you tried using a call to `history.push('/login')` on a failed authentication (i.e. within your catch clause)?

You may need to get access to the history object first by using the `useHistory` prop:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

// Within functional component
const history = useHistory()
```

You could also delay the loading of the component by adding a loading state boolean, which you start as false and then switch to true once the async call is completed and conditionally render your component once the loading is complete.

Appreciate this is different architecture to what you are currently using, but I think switching it around to this way might one way to fix your issue

Comment: I think the main problem is that React is not waiting to see if `loggedRef` is true and render the component. `history.push` doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: I've just added my Login component, idk if it is relevant..

Comment: Ok so in that case maybe try implementing the loading state part, so that the component only renders when the loaded state is true (i.e. the async has completed). You could render a 'loading spinner' type screen while loaded is false and then load your main component when loaded is true